# Gridlines in Julia PyPlot

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I'm using the "PyPlot" package in Julia, and I want to add gridlines at specified locations.  I'm not familiar enough with Python/Matlab to use their documentation pages to help - the commands differ in Julia.  I want a basic plot, with gridlines on both axes at intervals of 1:

```
using PyPlot
fig=figure("Name")
grid("on")
scatter([1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7])
```

Help appreciated...

Answer (score 7):

[PyPlot](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl) is just an interface to [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), so the commands
to customize the grid are Matplotlib's commands.

One way to configure the gridlines on both axes at intervals of 1 (for the given data) is:

```
using PyPlot

fig=figure(figsize=[6,3])
ax1=subplot(1,1,1) # creates a subplot with just one graphic

ax1[:xaxis][:set_ticks](collect(1:4))  # configure x ticks from 1 to 4
ax1[:yaxis][:set_ticks](collect(4:7))  # configure y ticks from 4 to 7

grid("on")
scatter([1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7])
```

This code was tested inside an [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl)'s notebook, and produces the following output:

[image: Output of plotting scatter 1,2,3,4 x 4,5,6,7]

Take a look at [Various Julia plotting examples using PyPlot](https://gist.github.com/gizmaa/7214002).

<sub>tested with Julia Version 0.4.3</sub>

Comment: This is very helpful!  As a further request, can the tick-mark labels be removed (I want a fine grid and I don't want the axes cluttered with numbers)... Thanks!

Comment: Sure! To remove the tick labels, you may use the commands: `ax1[:xaxis][:set_ticklabels]([])` and `ax1[:yaxis][:set_ticklabels]([])`, 
and to remove the tick marks: `ax1[:xaxis][:set_tick_params](which="major",length=0)` and `ax1[:yaxis][:set_tick_params](which="major",length=0)`. I also updated the answer with a link to some good examples of PyPlot's use. I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

The values where grid lines are drawn can be controlled by passing an array to the `xticks()` and `yticks()` functions.

A simple example:

```
using PyPlot
fig=figure("Name")
grid("on")

xticks(0:5)
yticks(3:8)

scatter([1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7])
```

---

If you want it to be more flexible you can figure out the limits based on your data and set the tick interval to something else.

One little more dynamic way to configure the x-axis of the grid could be:

```
x_data = [1,2,3,4]
x_tick_interval = 2;
x_tick_start = minimum(xdata)
x_tick_end   = maximum(xdata)
xticks(x_tick_start:x_tick_interval:x_tick_end)
```